# What does "hand with small restricted icon" status icon represent?

Tags: notification-icons

Can anyone help me identify this icon that looks like "a hand with small restricted icon", and how can I remove it?

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means [you have interruptions disabled](http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=6424). When your device is in this mode, you will not receive any visual, audible, or vibration notifications except for alarms you've explicitly configured to be allowed.

On vanilla/Google Android, this setting can be found in the "Sound & notifiation" category, but ASUS may have moved it elsewhere. Alternatively, if you press the volume button up when not in a media app (music player, video, etc) it should display the ringtone/notification volume overlay, and you can use that to adjust your interruption settings.

Answer (score 0):

I use Do Not Disturb a lot. I decided to turn it off and a hand icon appeared on the top left of my screen. I also received a call from an unknown number that my caller ID and blocker allowed. They said nothing when I answered.

Googling it gave me: it's disabling glove touch. In Android, I never used glove touch although that would be great. There are gestures that can be used on the Moto Stylus. I've checked for that and so far nothing.

My phone may be telling me to split the screen (if it gives suggestions as cookies do for shopping). I really have no definite answer. Perhaps this will help someone see options in their problem-solving.

Answer (score -1):

This is the sign for glove touch-sensitive. If you turn on the glove touch-sensitive, it will appear on the notification bar, but when you turn it off, it will not appear. For a solution in Asus, go to Setting - Asus customized setting - Glove mode and turn off the mode.